# Is there a way to save the command prompt into a variable and edit it?

Tags: bash, command-prompt

I've been trying to customize my bash command prompt with a shell script for some time now, but haven't had much success with it.

I'm trying to turn the prompt into something like this, with the Pos variables being strings or bash commands I've defined into the code.

```
PS1="[$PosZero][$PosOne][$PosTwo][$PosThree]$"
```

One thing I've tried to do save the current command prompt to a variable, and try and see if I can edit the contents of the brackets somehow, like so:

```
DEFAULT=$PS1
```

But what I've been struggling with is trying to edit the custom command prompt after having applied one already. If I'm attempting to change just one bracket, I want all the other brackets to keep whatever contents they have at the time. Instead, they erase themselves unless I pass the same information into the variables in the script.

I've been trying to find a way to parse the DEFAULT value (with the contents of PS1 within) to take out the contents of the brackets and apply them to the Pos variables. But I do not know how to do this. Does someone know how?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your requirement correctly. Do you want the expanded form of the prompt that you can edit? Like `PS1=ps1_value<keyboard cursor here>`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. I'm trying to write a script that gives you four positions (numbered from 0 to 3), in which you can stick a string or a bash command. I can do it once just fine, the problem is that when I try to do so again, the values given on the first go around are overwritten, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is what you want:

```
$ PS1='[$PosZero][$PosOne][$PosTwo][$PosThree]$ ' #Note: Use single quotes here, or escape $ as \$
[][][][]$ PosZero=abcd
[abcd][][][]$ PosOne=pqrs
[abcd][pqrs][][]$ PosZero=1234
[1234][pqrs][][]$ PosTwo=xyz
[1234][pqrs][xyz][]$ unset PosZero
[][pqrs][xyz][]$ PosOne=
[][][xyz][]$
```